# Latest vcbuild.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, windows-7

*What software package provides the latest version of `vcbuild.exe`?*

As far as I know, this tool is distributed with certain older versions of Microsoft's Windows SDK and Visual Studio. On my system, there is v7.1 of the SDK, and `vcbuild.exe` is not included, at least not in the default install.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense to me. Use the vcbuild that matches your VS.

Comment: I don't have VS installed. I only need `vcbuild.exe` to build a software. That's why I'm looking for a distribution which contains the tool, and as far as I know newer versions of VS don't contain `vcbuild.exe` anymore. So the answer to this question would be definite.

Comment: Well, what version of VS are you expected to use to build the software?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It just [says](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/Documentation/): "the free Windows SDK of Microsoft"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, vcbuild is not supplied with the Windows SDK. It is supplied with Visual Studio.

According to this [MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx), vcbuild was retired after VS2008. It is included in VS2008, but not VS2010.